# Calling Console.WriteLine from multiple threads

Tags: .net, console.writeline

Why does Console.WriteLine work from multiple threads?

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: @balpha - The question is *why does it work*, *what is the reason it works*.  There is nothing saying that it doesn't work.  Your comment is snide and offensive.

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't meant to sound this way. What it says is: The very fact that you ask this question suggests that you think it's a suprise that it does work. I really would have liked to know why, because I know pretty mouch nothing about multi-threading and its caveats. Apology if it sounded rude.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The console class handles the thread synchronization for you.

From the documentation of [Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx):

> I/O operations using these streams are
>   synchronized, which means multiple
>   threads can read from, or write to,
>   the streams.

Comment: @Reed is it synchronized by locking or with some other synchronization mechanism?

Comment: @Lirik It's handled on the native side, not using a managed lock.

Comment: I would like to add that the Console window (in Visual Studio) allows writing text from multiple threads, but you should be aware that the order in which the text is output may not be as expected, e.g. when adding large strings (like stack traces) they can even end up "garbled" or mixed. There is apparently no locking that ensures one `Write` is completed before another call starts pumping text into the stream.

Comment: I'm wondering, how long the text has to be to experience the garbling? I tried two similar programs, one in C++ with `cout` and another in C# with `Parallel.For` and `Console.Write`. While the C++ program did indeed give mixed output from different threads, the C# program displayed correct output and I couldn't find any way to corrupt it.

Comment: @mike Do you mean that the order of calling `Console.WriteLine` from multiple threads is not the same with the order in which text appears in the console? In other words, does Console.WriteLine writes asynchronously and not in the same order it was called?

Comment: @WriteEatSleepRepeat: The calls are posted to `Write` in the correct order and the output _starts_ in the correct order, but longer texts (e.g. stack traces) may be interrupted by shorter texts, sent later, but before the first text was fully output. At least that was my experience...

Comment: @WriteEatSleepRepeat: This does *not* apply to `WriteLine`.

Answer (score 11):

There is a bug in .NET 4.5 CLR which makes Console.WriteLine **not** work from multiple threads if you use Console.ReadKey. It is fixed in some Windows versions,  but in 8.1 Windows Update does not find it yet.

[Infrequent hangs in a multi-threaded C# console application when using Console.Writeline() or Console.Write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498756/infrequent-hangs-in-a-multi-threaded-c-sharp-console-application-when-using-cons)

[Using Console.WriteLine in a Timer why it would appear to exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357256/using-console-writeline-in-a-timer-why-it-would-appear-to-exit)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple threads write to the same output when using `Console.WriteLine`, generally your screen by default.

Comment: So Console.WriteLine is coded as thread safe then?  One thread blocks while the other writes?

Comment: It is - see my answer for the details from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

**The console and your code are 2 seperate applications**

The console window is not your application. A console application is invisable, your application does not contain the console. The console is installed into windows itself.

**Console.Writeline() is a Message**

It writes to a TextStream. Microsoft's console process simply waits for new streamtext to display.

**The 'Console Application' name does not make it a console**

The difference with ui projects is that a console application comes with a simplified set of references, and relies on input / output stream to communicate with the user.

You dont even need the console, you could build your own console, or use a debugger to view and write to it.

**Comparison with notepad**

If a file was a message, and notepad opened the filestream saved by your code. It wouldnt have mattered from which thread you saved the file. You are not accesing any ui.