# Access static method from static class from different threads. Is it safe?

Tags: .net, class, static, thread-safety

I have monitoring a folder using FileSystemWatcher to delete specified files from it. When FileSystemWatcher event is raised I create new thread to delete file. Is my code thread safe? 
I am not sure about static Log method which is accessed from Threads.

```
FileSystemWatcher.EventRaised....
{
   var delFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);
   var t = new Thread(DeleteThread.Do);
   t.Start(delFolder);
}
/*..code skip...*/



 static class DeleteThread
        {

            public static void Do(object delFolder)
            {
                try
                {
                    Log("Deleting folder {0}", (string)delFolder);
                    Directory.Delete((string)delFolder, true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log("Error deleting folder {0}. {1}", (string)delFolder, e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Log(string text, string text1 = "", string text2 = "", string text3 = "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text, text1, text2, text3);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is thread safe.
But this hasn't much to do with `static` methods, but with what the methods do.
Your `Log` method only calls `Console.WriteLine` which itself is thread safe according to the MSDN.

In short: Making a method `static` doesn't make it thread safe automatically.
But: Most `static` methods in the .NET Framework are implemented thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is basically, whether or not

```
Console.WriteLine("")
```

is thread-safe or not?
The answer is here: [Calling Console.WriteLine from multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079980/calling-console-writeline-from-multiple-threads) (YES)

It could cause you some race conditions, however.
Another thing, you could get multiple

```
   Directory.Delete()
```

calls in case your event will fire rapidly, causing many exceptions.

Comment: Unique folder will be passed to Directory.Delete() method, so I do not see any problems here.

Comment: What about nested folders? Multiple FileWatchers? That's why it "you **could** get".

Comment: That's right but I haven't explained that in my situation I have only top level folders without sub-folders. In general you are right!