# Bad loop of trouble put

Tags: c#, thread-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling Console.WriteLine from multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079980/calling-console-writeline-from-multiple-threads)

I am have test of CONSOLE APPLICATION for the c#

Question:

Has Console.WriteLine for THREAD SAFETY ?

In effect ,

is possible for no exceptions with :

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000000, p => Console.WriteLine("Hello Dears !"));
```

Thank for quick reponse !

Comment: Are you asking "Is `Console.WriteLine()` thread safe"?

Comment: @Widor yes i need more characters

Comment: yes comment is not of much of length i must only to say yes

Comment: Please change the spelling and grammar of your post. The title and the question are not clear.

Comment: @Emo i only have use of poor mobile interface. stack commonity of much help for update to internet english

Comment: @Erno, why not just vote to close? Obviously English is not his/her first language. It's like telling a right-fielder to improve his pitching. Seems a bit mean...

Comment: @PRASHANTP I'm curious - all of your other questions seem to be articulate and well written. Why not this one?

Comment: @JamesHill - because his other posts are much better. I do not vote for closing immediately because the question can be improved and prove to be useful.

Comment: @Widor because "stack commonity of much help for update to internet english". Be sure to look at revision 1 :)

Comment: @Erno, I checked out the other posts and you're absolutely right. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using console I/O is thread safe:

> "I/O operations using these streams are synchronized, which means
>   multiple threads can read from, or write to, the streams."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx

Related: [Calling Console.WriteLine from multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079980/calling-console-writeline-from-multiple-threads)