# Use Parallel.ForEach without lists

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I want to use `Parallel.ForEach` as a multi-threading method that executes a code without lists or file reading.

I want to do it like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach
{
      Console.WriteLine("test");
}
```

So it will write `test` without stopping. I will use an `IF` statement to check if it should be stopped or no.

Is it possible to use `Parallel.ForEach` like that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you wanna use a `foreach` loop without anything to iterate on? what's the main goal here? `ForEach` seems irrelevant.

Comment: @SelmanGenç - I want it to execute a normal code not iterated on a List.

Comment: Why do you want to use a construct to iterate over a list you don't have? Please explain how would you do it using a normal `foreach`

Comment: @NirmalSubedi - I want it to be multi-threaded.

Comment: OP, it makes no sense to repeat something forever in parallel. That sentence isn't even comprehensible to me. What are you trying to do overall?

Comment: [`Parallel.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-use-parallel-invoke-to-execute-parallel-operations)?

Comment: @JohnWu - I am trying to write `test` for example more faster by multi-threading.

Comment: If you have a series of tests, wouldn't they be in a list, and wouldn't you iterate over that? If you don't have a series of tests but only a single test, again, I do not understand what your goal is here.

Comment: Instead of checking some condition in an `if` statements (as you mentioned in your question), you can just use it as a condition for a loop: `while (someCondition == true) { Console.WriteLine("Test"); }`

Comment: `I want it to be multi-threaded.` **Why** do you want it multi-threaded? `Console.WriteLine` is going to use a locking mechanism anyway (i.e. will 'thwart' your attempts at multiple threads) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079980/calling-console-writeline-from-multiple-threads . _If what you are trying to do is improve the performance of `Console.WriteLine` then reduce your number of calls to it. Don't write the string 100 times. Build a `string` which contains 100 lines of data and then call `Console.WriteLine` just once. It will be **way** quicker._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not very clear but you may try this approach:

```
        var parallelDrege = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        while (true)
        {
            Parallel.For(0, parallelDrege, t =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test");
            });
        }
```

Set parallelDegre to the desired value and be aware that every batch will be processed in parallel but from batch to batch is a sequetial process.

Hope this help!

Comment: how do i terminate this ?

Comment: go with the number of CPUs

Comment: Environment.ProcessorCount

Comment: or a factor of this: 2*Environment.ProcessorCount may be better

Answer (score 1):

Multi-threading this is not going to achieve anything, but if you insist:

```
bool _shouldStop { get; set; } = false;
bool _shouldStopSecondThread { get; set; } = false;

public static Main(string[] args)
{

Thread thread = new Thread(print);
Thread anotherThread = new Thread(anotherPrint);
thread.Start();
anotherThread.Start();

//your code here while the worker writes "Test" to console

if(condition) {
   _shouldStop=true;
   _shouldStopSecondThread=false; 
}
}    
//...

public void print()
{
   while (!_shouldStop)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("test");
   }
   Console.WriteLine("worker terminated");
}

public void anotherPrint()
{
   while (!_shouldStopSecondThread)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("test");
   }
   Console.WriteLine("worker terminated");
}
```

Comment: In addition I strongly suggest you to update to the Task API over the old Threading one.